# Android navigation button mess layout even though there is enough space below

Tags: android

When i design the layout the layout looks like this

[image]

As you can see there is alot of space left below the buttons but when my app is run the layout looks like this

[image]

In the emulator there is no space left at the bottom.I dont know why this is happenin but my space should be there and its not showing in run time.
Here is my layout code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="554dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/insert"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="82dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rview"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.373"
            android:hint="#"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/remove"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="82dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="132dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rview"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.351"
            android:hint="#"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_insert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="insert"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/remove"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rview"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_remove"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="remove"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rview"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.384" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: This issue appeared before adding NestedScrollView as root element. i have set NestedScrollvView as root because i want my softkeyboard to push layput up when it appears.

Comment: You're using fixed sizes for your layouts and so they are being displayed the same physical size on all devices. Have a look at some tutorials for constraint layout and read up on using the `match_constraint` size property

Comment: Ok I will try doing some research on constraint layout. thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following, it may require little changes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rview"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/insert"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="82dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="#"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.373" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/remove"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="82dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="132dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="#"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.351" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_insert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="insert"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/remove"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_remove"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="remove"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.384" />
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well this solved my problem so i am going to accept this answer.

Comment: @M.Ahmed an upvote will be appreciated. Happy coding.